# should I add ns_return / ns_respond to my code?

Tags: javascript, ajax, tcl

I am new to learning tcl and adp ,, my ajax code is not returning result from the tcl file though it sends a request so I thought maybe I should add a command for response , please assist me with below code :

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <form action=""> 
    <input value="Get Time" type="button" onclick="showCurrentTime();" name="GetTime">
    <div id="result" align="center"></div>
    </form>
    <script language="Javascript">
    function showCurrentTime()
    {
var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)  { 
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();  
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","time.tcl",true); 
    xmlhttp.send();
}
    }
    </script>

    </body>
```

please note that the tcl file is working properly to print the time , so if I need to add the commands ns_return or the command ns_respond please add some explanation ,
thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find it easier to use the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library in your Javascript, as that allows you to write your client-side code more succinctly. (Note that I like to put links used in my Javascript in the `<head>` section and then pull them in by reference as this aids debugging in complex cases.)

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <link id="timer" href="time.tcl" />
</head>
<body>
<form action=""> 
<input value="Get Time" type="button" onclick="showCurrentTime();" name="GetTime">
<div id="result" align="center"></div>
</form>
<script language="Javascript">
var timerURL = $("#timer")[0].href;
function showCurrentTime() {
    $.get(timerURL, function(response) {
        $("#result").html(response);
    });
}
</script>
</body>
```

Next, you need to check what the content type of the response from the server is. You *should* make sure that it is `text/plain` if I've understood what you're trying to do in this case. If I've read the documentation for [`ns_respond`](http://panoptic.com/wiki/aolserver/Ns_respond) right, you want to do something like:

```tcl
ns_respond -type "text/plain" -string [clock format [clock seconds]]
```

More generally, returning JSON is often even more useful though you then want slightly different techniques for displaying it.

Comment: You could also use `ns_return 200 text/plain [clock format [clock seconds]]` I suppose. `ns_respond` is a bit more flexible though.

Comment: Many thanks @Donal Fellows for the great help and for the jquery code it is much simpler :) but i'm still not used to it ...
it worked out perfectly :) Thank you again and again !